# How do I auto-restore NuGet packages for my .NET6 custom control when an application references it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-6.0, nuget-package-restore

How do I auto-restore NuGet packages for my .NET6 custom control when a .NET6 application references the custom control DLL itself?

Is there any instruction I can give to my assembly to auto-restore NuGet packages when necessary? Otherwise, when you build the app you get this error:

> error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly
> 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Either explicitly load this assembly
> using a method such as LoadFromAssemblyPath() or use a
> MetadataAssemblyResolver that returns a valid assembly. Line 14
> Position 97.'

The assembly `*.json` file is like the following:

```
{
 "runtimeTarget": {
 "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0",
 "signature": ""
},
"compilationOptions": {},
"targets": {
".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0": {
  "Manufacturer.ProductName/1.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.7.0",
      "System.Buffers": "4.5.1",
      "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager": "6.0.0",
      "System.Data.DataSetExtensions": "4.5.0",
      "System.Management": "6.0.0",
      "System.Memory": "4.5.4",
      "System.Numerics.Vectors": "4.5.0",
      "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe": "6.0.0",
      "System.ServiceModel.Primitives": "4.9.0",
      "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages": "6.0.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "Manufacturer.ProductName.dll": {}
    }
  },
  "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/5.0.0": {
    "runtime": {
      "lib/netstandard2.1/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "5.0.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "5.0.20.51904"
      }
    }
  },
  "Microsoft.CSharp/4.7.0": {},
  "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/5.0.10": {
    "runtime": {
      "lib/net5.0/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "5.0.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "5.0.1021.41022"
      }
    }
  },
  "Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents/6.0.0": {
    "runtime": {
      "lib/net6.0/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "6.0.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "6.0.21.52210"
      }
    },
    "runtimeTargets": {
      "runtimes/win/lib/net6.0/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll": {
        "rid": "win",
        "assetType": "runtime",
        "assemblyVersion": "6.0.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "6.0.21.52210"
      }
    }
  },

  ...
```

Comment: You thing itself is a nuget package that others can use? Or just a compiled assembly that is referenced or a source code project that is referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to restore Nuget packages for your custom control when an application reference it. Firstly, you should know what is a DLL and how it works. For more information about dll you can refer to:[DDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library)

Here’s an example I test in VS to explain dll file.

1 When you reference a nuget package(Newtonsoft.Json) in a project A ,it will install this package to your global-packages folder that has default path and you can override the folder path.[global-packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

2  when you build project A, it will generate a .dll file in your Debug/Release folder that can be referenced by other projects later.
At the same time, the Nuget packages will be generated as dll in the same folder.
[image]

3 when you reference .dll file from project A in project B ,you can right click project B and select “And Referenc”.After adding .dll file, you will see reference under Dependencies in project B.You can use function or method in project A by adding .dll file into Dependencies without restoring Nuget Packages.

[image]

When a program or a DLL uses a DLL function in another DLL, a dependency is created. The program is no longer self-contained, and the program may experience problems if the dependency is broken.From your error information, it cannot find the `System.Drawing.Common` when building app.

Here’re suggestions you can check:

1 check the build folder in your your project (.NET6 custom control) and make sure whether the package.dll exists.

2 check your application project’s dependencies list and make sure the dll file is referenced successfully.

3 check your dll file and make sure Whether it is removed from the computer.

4 check your dll file and make sure whether it is overwritten with an earlier version or upgrated.

At lats, you can try to build a new dll file and add it to reference again.